# Effect of CONVERT_IMPLICIT

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In the application which we are developing, there is a scenario where a stored procedure is called to claim a session. In a nut shell, this SP checks for a session based on the input parameter and deletes the session if (extract from specifications)

- Logic
- Delete the session row where the following conditions exist:
- The session row has not expired (`EXPIRES > SYSUTCDATETIME()`).

Here is the code to perform this task:

```
DELETE SESSIONS
WHERE SESSION_ID = @p_session_id
  AND EXPIRES > SYSUTCDATETIME();
```

The `SESSION_ID` column is the PK and has the default clustered index. The data type is uniqueidentifier. `EXPIRES` is of datatype `datetimeoffset(0)`.

Here is the problem - SQL Server does a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` and this causes an index scan. To add to my misery, the customer refuses to share meta-data about the DB and I have no clue how many rows of data the production version will have. The customer is of the opinion that the code needs to be as efficient as possible, no matter what the final DB size will be.

Is there any way to address this, apart from using CAST to do an explicit conversion of `SYSUTCDATETIME()` to `datetimeoffset(0)`?

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: "the customer refuses to share meta-data about the DB" ... lol?

Comment: :) Such is life. It takes all kinds, I guess

Comment: @Rah nevermind, but this is very strange if you try to solve database issues of your customer while db's metadata are hidden...

Comment: What do mean, "no metadata"? You must know the datatypes to run the query and see the plan...

Comment: I know all of that. The bit that is missing is DB metrics such as How many concurrent users? What would be the size of the DB in PROD? Sorry if I used the term metadata too broadly and confused you.

Answer (score 1):

May be will be better:

```
DELETE SESSIONS
WHERE SESSION_ID = @p_session_id
  AND EXPIRES > SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
```